# Passenger gem getting updated for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

I have a staging server from my client which has passenger(3.0.5 and 3.0.2) installed on it for an rails app(v=2.3.13), but when I start the server using passenger on the console it's getting updated to 3.0.5-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.3-1002. In my **Gemfile** I have mentioned

```
gem 'passenger', '=3.0.5'
```

Why is it getting updated?

Thanks in advance.

```
Here's the log....

when I run the command, **`**RAILS_ENV=staging passenger start**.`**
__________________________________________________________
Nginx core 0.8.54 isn't installed

Phusion Passenger Standalone will automatically install it into:

    /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.5-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.3-1002/nginx-0.8.54

This will only be done once. Please sit back and relax while installation is
in progress.

Checking for required software...

GNU C++ compiler... found at `/usr/bin/g++`
GNU make... found at `/usr/bin/make`
A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
Ruby development headers... found
OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
RubyGems... found
Rake... found at `/usr/local/bin/rake`
rack... found
Curl development headers with SSL support... found
OpenSSL development headers... found
Zlib development headers... found
file-tail... found
daemon_controller >= 0.2.5... found

Downloading Passenger binaries for your platform, if available...

Resolving standalone-binaries.modrails.com... 97.107.130.55
Connecting to standalone-binaries.modrails.com|97.107.130.55|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-10-09 08:52:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Looks like it's not. But don't worry, the necessary binaries will be compiled from source instead.

Downloading Nginx binaries for your platform, if available...
# 

    Resolving standalone-binaries.modrails.com... 97.107.130.55
    Connecting to standalone-binaries.modrails.com|97.107.130.55|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2013-10-09 08:52:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Looks like it's not. But don't worry, the necessary binaries will be compiled from source instead.

Downloading Nginx...



     # wget -O /tmp/root-passenger-standalone-21842/nginx-0.8.54.tar.gz http://nginx.org/download/nginx-0.8.54.tar.gz
        --2013-10-09 08:52:00--  http://nginx.org/download/nginx-0.8.54.tar.gz
        Resolving nginx.org... 206.251.255.63
        Connecting to nginx.org|206.251.255.63|:80... connected.
        HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
        Length: 650001 (635K) [application/octet-stream]
        Saving to: '/tmp/root-passenger-standalone-21842/nginx-0.8.54.tar.gz'
        100%

    [======================================================================================================>] 650,001      788K/s   in 0.8s    
        2013-10-09 08:52:01 (788 KB/s) - `/tmp/root-passenger-standalone-21842/nginx-0.8.54.tar.gz' saved [650001/650001]

Installing Phusion Passenger Standalone...
```

Comment: You don't need to mention `passenger` in the `Gemfile`. See documentation here [9.4.1. Does Phusion Passenger itself need to be added to the Gemfile?](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#add_passenger_to_gemfile)

Comment: Even if I remove the gem from the file and start passenger it's still updating to 3.0.5-x86_64-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.3-1002 and does not use the existing gem(3.0.5)..!

Comment: @user2634784 what do you mean by updating? is it downloading the gem from a server?

Comment: @phoet yes it is downloading from the server and not using the existing one.

Comment: @user2634784 who is starting that download? is it bundler or what? could you show some logs?